# colors in plotly - ‘range’ not meaningful for factors

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

anybody can help? trying to create plotly scatter chart where I can change color of selected markers. I checked the dataframe source and indt$active is a num, not factor, yet plotly chart interprets it as a factor
see the code, everything is fine until i set `color = ~active`. I tried using inside the reactive `indt$active <- as.numeric(as.character( indt$active ))` but it still does nothing. I am struggling to find what factor the chart fails on. It fails to load (you can comment out the color=~active to see without the error). *To select values, you need to draw a box*

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


tms<-format(seq(as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 00:00:00", tz="GMT"), 
                length.out=48, by='30 min'), '%H:%M')
dts<-c( "Day Before BH","BH","Sunday","Saturday","Friday","Thursday","Wednesday","Tuesday", "Monday" )

indt <- as.data.frame(matrix( c(0), nrow=9,  ncol=48, byrow = TRUE))
indt<-cbind(dts,indt)

colnames(indt) <- c("dt",tms)

indt<-gather(indt,tm,active,-dt)

pal <- c("red", "blue")
pal <- setNames(pal, c(0, 1))



ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {



  ind<-reactive({
    d <- event_data("plotly_selected")
    indt[d$pointNumber+1,3]<-1
    indt<<-indt
    return(indt)
  })


  output$plot <- renderPlotly({


    f1 <- list(size = 8) 

    yform <- list(title = "",
                  categoryorder = "array",
                  categoryarray = dts
                  ,tickfont = f1)



    plot_ly(ind()
            , x = ~tm, y = ~dt, mode = "markers", type = "scatter", 
            color = ~active, 
            colors = pal,
            marker = list(size = 20)

    ) %>%
      layout(dragmode = "select") %>%
      layout(xaxis = list(title = "", tickfont = f1), 
             yaxis = yform)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your plot_ly function try using `color = ~as.character(active)`instead of `color = ~active`

Comment: could not be easier. Before i asked i had tried 'color = ~as.integer(as.character(active))' , it did not work, i do not why, so i looked for the error somewhere else